# How to create a custom Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to write a document which will contain a preliminary table of contents for a report that I need to write couple of months later.

For that, I need to provide the preliminary outline, the question is, how to create a ToC with arbitrary entries in it (not related to the document which is being written now)?

Comment: You can use `\addcontentsline`. For example, `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}`

Comment: can you show me a more extended example of how it works? excuse my n00bness

Comment: You have to elaborate more on your use case. Where do you want the toc? Along with current document's toc or is it inside the body of the current document?

Comment: inside the body of the current document, completely unrelated from the current toc

Comment: Then you can simply use a list. i will post an example code shortly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumerate` and to style it, use `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-2]
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,leftmargin=*,labelsep=2ex,ref=\arabic*]
    \item First chapter \dotfill 2
      \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*,leftmargin=*,labelsep=2ex]
        \item First section \dotfill 3
        \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*,leftmargin=*,labelsep=2ex]
        \item First sub section \dotfill 4
      \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
    \item Second chapter \dotfill 10
      \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*,leftmargin=*,labelsep=2ex]
        \item First section \dotfill 12
        \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*,leftmargin=*,labelsep=2ex]
        \item First sub section \dotfill 13
      \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More styling like adjusting the vertical separation etc can be done and left as an exercise. For details, refer `enumitem` manual.